# Is it possible to send file to Azure Event Hubs?

Tags: file, azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I want to send .zip files to Event Hubs and then listen the Event Hub with a console application and receive this file to unzip it. Is Event Hubs the correct solution for this ?

I need a relaible solution for this because there will be thousands of clients that will send .zip files to my Event Hub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible to send files to Event Hubs by sending the file contents as byte array but it is not recommended because the [`maximum size of event data is 256KB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee732538.aspx).

Better approach would be to upload the zip files in blob storage and send the link to those blobs as event data. On the client side when you fetch the event data, extract the blob url and download the blobs.

Comment: So how about scalability. Event Hubs have partitions that can be automatically scale. By this way Event Hub can consume millions of events per second. Does blob storage have similar features ? How can I make sure input troughput ?

Comment: You can check the scalability targets for blob storage here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/. To achieve scalability, what you could do is write files in separate storage accounts instead of just one storage account.

Comment: My goal was also to listen incoming .zip files and unzip them with an Event Processor and save content to HDInsight storage. In this scenario then, my Event Processor will listen Event Hub and each Event will have the path of the .zip file that is saved to the Blob Storage. Then Event Processor will go and get the file from Blob Storage, unzip it and put the contents in HDInsight storage. Maybe delete the .zip file at the end.

Comment: Any reason you can't just issue a short lived SAS token for blob storage and monitor the storage logs for the arrival of the file? You could partition multiple storage accounts to help you get the needed throughput. If you don't want to create code to monitor the storage accounts, just use event hub to process "new file has been uploaded" events.

Comment: I think monitoring storage logs is good idea but propbably it will need a scheduled task for checking the logs in other words it won't be a realtime process. On the other hand, like you suggested Event Hubs will give me real time notifications for each file arrival and unzipping process could start as soon as possible. I think this will be the reasonable solution. Thank you all for your time !!

Comment: The problem with monitoring storage logs is that the logs would contain all activities that are happening on your storage account. In order to find if a file has been uploaded, you would need to parse the log file and find all the relevant `PUT BLOB` and `PUT BLOCK LIST` operations. I believe it is a cumbersome task compared with sending an event in Event Hub and the client just consuming the event.